# PhpSpreadsheet cannot read specific xls file

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

The following error
`Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception: Parameter pos=-12 is invalid`
is given when trying to parse a specific xls file.

Code

```
$inputFileName = "excel.xls";
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xls');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
```

The file in question: https://filebin.net/sle19tm0kdgduyne/excel.xls?t=u0itbeue

I have tried using all available readers such as `Xlsx`, `Csv` etc and even using the old deprecated `PHPExcel` library. Nothing can parse this specific file, even though it opens fine with excel on windows.

My end goal is converting this xls file to an array, so i can paste the data into a database.

Comment: have you tried to just read cell data,  ignore styling, data validation, …: `$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();`, `$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);`, `$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);` - as suggested [Read data only](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/)

Comment: @lovelace No, but i just gave it a shot and got the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to use `createReader()`.

Here the example of my worked code.

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('path/to/file.xls');
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This gives the same error and the code is pretty much identical to what i allready have. The only difference is that I use the IoFactory class to get the Xls reader object.

Comment: Sorry can't help. I don't know where exactly the problem is, in my project everything is worked.